# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule in functions.php returns 404

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I tried to add following codes in function.php to add my own rewrite rule, but it returns 404:

```
add_rewrite_rule('all_comments/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=all_comments&post_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

And it also returns 404 when I simply tried to write a test rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule('testss$', 'index.php', 'top');
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);
```

There must be something wrong with my add_rewrite_rule function, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I found out it's a plugin called **Rewrite** that uses its own rules list instead of my own rules list. I deleted it and it works now.